# Change the order of the given string in a specific way

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, typescript

I have a string for example '12:13:45.123  UTC Sun Oct 17 2021' and I am looking to change the string into 'Sun Oct 17 2021 12:13:45.123  UTC'.

I do it with

> str.slice(18)+' '+str.slice(0,17)

.

but the question is - how can I avoid call slice twice? is there a way to make it more elegant way and efficient?

BTW - I am not looking to split and concat the substrings.

Comment: Something this tiny does not _need_ to be made "more efficient." You'd probably have to process hundreds of thousands of such values, before "efficiency" would come even close to being a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `replace` with a regex:

```js
const str = '12:13:45.123 UTC Sun Oct 17 2021';

console.log(str.replace(/(.{16}) (.*)/, '$2 $1'));
```

IMHO it's more elegant but according to https://jsbench.me/ your code is faster.